# I am trying to let a user of an ionic 2 application delete a list item. Built using Firebase using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

The below code shows my create a list method, the HTML and the delete method. I am struggling to get the delete method working. I get the error 'remove is undefined'? I am not sure If I have to add the $key in the delete method?

```
//Delete method, this is the method I am struggling. i want a user to be able to delete the list item on slide
deleteList(list) {
    list.remove(list);
   }

//HTML
<ion-list>
     <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let list of list" >
         <ion-item>
           <p>An item:
             <strong>{{list.list1}}</strong>
           </p>
           <p>Oooooh is this important:
             <strong>{{list.list2}}</strong>
           </p>
            <p>Another item:
             <strong>{{list.list3}}</strong>
            </p>    
       </ion-item>

         <ion-item-options side="left">
             <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteList(list.$key)">
                <ion-icon name="md-trash">Delete</ion-icon>
             </button>
        </ion-item-options>
       </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-list>

//Create list

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.listRef = firebase
          .database()
          .ref(`/userProfile/${user.uid}/List`);
      }
    });
  }

    createList(
    list1: string,
    list2: string,
    list3: string

  ): ThenableReference {
    return this.listRef.push({
      list1: list1,
      list2: list2,
      list3: list3,
    });
  }
```

[Firebase Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fyxxi.png)

Comment: where is your remove function? where do you want to delete it from firebase storage?

Comment: Yes delete from firebase database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some mistakes in your code.You probably wanted to use *ngFor="let list of lists" // lists is the array or collection on which you want to use the loop and list is just a reference(which you could use anything) of the items present inside the lists collection

Second mistake is that inside the delete function you should use the reference you are using to reference you firebase database in your case you should have used this.listRef not list

for deleting you could use something like this(assuming you have keys inside your list(firebase keys))

```
<ion-item-options side="left">
  <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteList(list.$key)">
    <ion-icon name="md-trash">Delete</ion-icon>
  </button>
</ion-item-options>
```

It is always advisable to use service for these operations as you will have all your firebase related operations and ref at one central place and you could easily use it from any page.

The simplest way to delete data is to call remove() on a reference to the location of that data(from firebase docs)
so you can use this to delete the selected item from the firebase storage:

you can get the authenticated user or current logged in user from:

```
import { User } from 'firebase/app'; // import user from firebase

authenticatedUser: User; //declare variable authenticatedUser as type User

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    this.authenticatedUser = user;
}
```

then delete:

```
deleteList(key) {
firebase
   .database()
    .ref(`/userProfile/${this.authenticatedUser.uid}/List/${key}`).remove()
}
```

Comment: where do i put firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    this.authenticatedUser = user;
}

Comment: If you are doing all this inside one ts file put it inside the constructor or ionic's ionViewDidLoad() method

Comment: I'm Getting an error when I put it in either   public list: Array<any>;
   constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public eventProvider: EventProvider
    
  ) {}
  

 
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.eventProvider.getlist().on('value', listSnapshot => {
      this.list = [];
      listSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
        this.list.push({
          id: snap.key,
          list1: snap.val().list1,
          list2: snap.val().list2,
          list3: snap.val().list3
        });
        return false;
      });
    });
    
    
  }

Comment: When I put into the constructor -  ";" is missing .... its says this in multiple locations

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: firebase is not defined
ReferenceError: firebase is not defined

Comment: did you install firebase. if you did, did you import it in the page you are using it. if not import it first as import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

Comment: No errors now but its not deleting the list out of the system

Comment: are you getting your key inside the delete function and match it with the firebase key check if both the keys are same for the item you want to delete

Comment: The key which you are passing in the delete function... Console.log it inside the function and check what is the key you get... After that check in firebase console's database if that is the correct key of the item which you want to delete from firebase

Comment: Can you produce a jsfiddle of just the basic code you are trying no need of including firebase just your html and ts

Comment: can you just show me your database list how are you storing your items .maybe a screenshot of your database. you can attach a picture of it in your question

Comment: i saw your fiddle there are lots of mistakes in it. i need to see how are you storing data inside firebase

Comment: I have added the image

Comment: Brilliant its allowing me to delete it now :D .. Now though its not outputting my lists can I just show you my push method on jsfiddle

Comment: If it helped please mark the answer as helpful and correct brother

Comment: Mark my answer and we will then check about your list

Comment: Helps been great

Comment: Hey Mahesh, the delete function is working. But the items are now not being show. On the item one it just shows [object object]

Answer (score -1):

First thing is you write wrong `*ngFor="let list of list"`
It's written like this `*ngFor="let list of lists"`.
Remove method also not there so I give and example:

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let item of shoppingItems | async">
  <ion-item>
    {{ item.$value }}
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item-options side="right">
    <button ion-button color="danger" icon-only (click)="removeItem(item.$key)"><ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-item-options>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

On typescript only Write That

First Make Privoder and Import It.

```
import { DatabaseserviceProvider } from './../../providers/databaseservice/databaseservice';

constructor(public firebaseProvider: DatabaseserviceProvider)

removeItem(id) {
    this.firebaseProvider.removeItem(id);
}
```

databaseservice.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';

// import { AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable, AngularFireAuth, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable()
export class DatabaseserviceProvider {

    constructor (
        public http: Http,
        // private _af: AngularFire,
        public afd: AngularFireDatabase) {
        console.log('Hello Database serviceProvider Provider');
    }

    getShoppingItems() {
        return this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/');
    }

    addItem(name) {
        this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/').push(name);
    }

    removeItem(id) {
        this.afd.list('/shoppingItems/').remove(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, so I use the remove function in provider class and not the list class?

Comment: yes if you are use provider class to use easy to anywhere and also please  It's written like this *ngFor="let list of lists".

Comment: As a user is logged wtih a unique ID this wont delet their nodes list?